# Does try-with resource on db connection pool close the connection each time?

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement, connection-pooling, try-with-resources

I'm using HikariDataSource for managing the connection pool to my Postgres DB.

I'm using try with a resource for getting the connection from HikariDataSource and i want to understand the following:

1. Is the connection is really close each time?
2. If yes - There are no pros of working with prepared statements this way?
3. What is the best practice for using prepared statements with a connection pool?

Here is my connection code:

```
public <T> CompletableFuture<T> withConnection(FunctionThatThrowsChecedException<Connection, T> action) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection()) {
                return action.apply(connection);
            } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("error while getting collection", e);
            }
        }, workerThreads);
    }
```

Here some example of executing query with a prepared statement:

```
public CompletableFuture<Integer> delete(String batchId) {
        return postgresProvider.withConnection(connection -> {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(DELETE_QUERY);

            ps.setString(1, batchId);
            return ps.executeUpdate();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

1. No, the connection is returned to the pool when `close()` is called. The connection pool's `Connection` wrapper overrides `close()` that way so the pool can work.
2. It's not closed.
3. Just like you normally do. Using a connection pool rarely requires anything special, and if you intend to tune the pool you need to measure performance and actually know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I saw many examples of initializing new connection pools that declaring using cache to true. I'm trying to read PGSimpleDataSource caching default with no luck. Why all examples declare it to true when you say that it rarely requires anything special?

Comment: @Udi I have no idea what kind of examples you've been looking at. Maybe the db/cp combo does require that configuration, maybe you're reading low quality tutorials. I just said that whether you use a connection pool or not, the way you use `PreparedStatement` remains the same. I didn't say the connection pool doesn't require configuration, although for example HikariCP has great defaults.

Comment: The difference between using cp or not from the code point of view is if I'm not using CP so I can create the Prepared statement globally in the class level right after I'm initializing my connection and then use it whenever i want. When using cp i need to create new PS in the function level like i did above because each time it can be a different connection. Do you agree with that?

Comment: @Udi global `PreparedStatements` are unnecessary and irrelevant. It doesn't give you prepared statement caching either, since that's handled on the database side. You'd need to have a decent grasp of the JDBC spec (and driver specific oddities) to understand what's really happening. Prepared statement caching isn't as simple as you make it out to be. You may be caching a `PreparedStatement` with your global variable, but that's not the equivalent as "caching a prepared statement", which is what the database does perfectly fine without your global vars.

Comment: @Kayman Thank you very much. I didn't know that. I will give more read about it. Thanks again